# MongoDB - Find values that contain whitespace

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following sample documents:

```
[
    { _id: "1", value: " 1" },
    { _id: "2", value: "2" },
    { _id: "3", value: "3 " }
]
```

How can I run a MongoDB `find` function that returns the document(s) with a value that contains a space? So in this case, it would return 1 because it has a space at the beginning, and 3 because it has a space at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$regex` operator with regex pattern:

```
(^\s.+)|(.+\s$)
```

`(^\s.*)` - Group (`()`) with starts with (`^`) whitespace (`\s`) match any character (`.`) with at least one occurrence.

`|` - Or.

`(.*\s$)` - Group (`()`) with match any character (`.`) with at least one occurrence (`+`) at the end (`$`).

[Sample Regex 101 and Test Data](https://regex101.com/r/R6OtQh/1)

---

```
db.collection.find({
  value: {
    $regex: "(^\\s.+)|(.+\\s$)"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LVUqUw-4Yu6)